# DeploymentPlanModifier with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I have been trying my luck with DeploymentPlanModifier, based on some great input from Ed Elliott.

I have issues with using the contributor, and all the samples that exists and that target the issue are with the visual studio 2013 (12) and I use VS 2015 (14). The issues were first being unable to load the contributor, and then when following the advice of Ed to reference the dlls in the Extensions folder I get this error:

> The extension type
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment.Internal.InternalDeploymentPlanExecutor
>   could not be instantiated

The path I used is

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130\Extensions\

I also have a folder called

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Extensions\

which one to use?
Are there known issues or changes with VS 2015?

I am targeting SQL Server Azure Dbs and SQL Server 2016

Comment: I would try downloading this nuget package and making all of your dac references point to it: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x86/ (ScriptDom, Dac etc) - does that work?

Comment: I had done what you suggested, I intalled the nuget package, build it. I then moved the files from the build (that is my dll and pdb, and alle the other dlls and files that were placed at the build result forlder).

I got back to the original message of the required contributor with id xxx could not be loaded.

Comment: Can you share it? There are a couple of things I would normally try as well - are you comfortable with pro non? Try setting up a path, contains filter for  the name - is it even loaded at all?

Comment: Well I do not mind sharing the project of the contributor, it has no IP or other critical parts. Would a zip file on OneDrive be OK?

-I do not know what "pro non" is - sorry.

-Regading the last question, I can verify that VS does get a hold of the file, as it does not allow me to delete the dll's from the IDE folder while VS is still running and the solution is open. The error I get however, suggests that it cannot load it.